# System Generated Array

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've been working on a sorting algorithm and one condition says that the elements in the array should be program generated.

This is the code I've been working on.

```
        int f;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter how many elements you want to be sorted:");
        f = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] myArray = new int[f];
        
        int smallest, tmp;

        Console.WriteLine("Unsorted List");
        foreach (int a in myArray)
            Console.Write(a + " ");

       
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            smallest = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < myArray.Length; j++)
            {
                if (myArray[j] < myArray[smallest])
                {
                    smallest = j;
                }

                tmp = myArray[smallest];
                myArray[smallest] = myArray[i];
                myArray[i] = tmp;
            }

           
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nSorted List Using Selection Sort:");
        for (int i=0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(myArray[i] + " ");
```

The result of this program is just 0. How can I make the elements in array program generated? Is there a specific code block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note we should use `i < myArray.Length` to Iterate the array instead of `i < myArray.Length-1`.

You can try the following code to add the elements in program generated array.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int f;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter how many elements you want to be sorted:");
            f = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] myArray = new int[f];
            int temp = 0;
            int minIndex = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Unsorted List");
            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
            {
                myArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
            {
                minIndex = i;
                for (int j = i; j < myArray.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (myArray[j] < myArray[minIndex])
                    {
                        minIndex = j;
                    }
                }
                temp = myArray[minIndex];
                myArray[minIndex] = myArray[i];
                myArray[i] = temp;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nSorted List Using Selection Sort:");
            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(myArray[i] + " ");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Besides, I have modified the related code about Selection Sort, which makes it can produce the correct sort.

Result:

[image]

Update for generate the random array:

```
    int f;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter how many elements you want to be sorted:");
    f = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] myArray = new int[f];
    Random randNum = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = randNum.Next(1, 100);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The radnom array is ");
    foreach (var item in myArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this, but does c# has a specific code block on how the elements of the array is generated by the program?

Comment: @tayblinks live, how do you want to generate the elements by the program? Such as  generate an array randomly?

Comment: Yes, is that possible?

Comment: @tayblinks live, I have updated my code for the random array.

Comment: So much thanks for this!!! <3 This will really help me a lot